# no se suben los archivos del repositorio local a GitHub

Tags: git, github

Tengo un repo local y cree el repo remoto, hice la conexión de local y remoto en git bash. pero cuando haga el pull para traer el archivo README de hub a local no se copia en la carpeta del proyecto, sin embargo el estado del pull es positivo. intente forzar el push para subir los archivos a GitHub, pero tampoco aparecen en GitHub y el estado que me arroja la consola es el siguiente:

[image: Resultados en consola bash]

cambie el nombre de los repositorios. Borre el remoto con git remote rm origin y luego realice el proceso de añadir de nuevo el repo remoto con git remote add origin urlHTTP. Tenia el repositorio privado en github y lo cambien a publico
Y aun asi no funciona.

Que puedo hacer para que me aparezcan los archivos? que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias

Comment: En lo que muestras no es evidente lo que esperas que pase y no pasa. No vemos en qué rama está el readme y ahí se ve que bajaste 46 archivos...

Comment: primero debes hacer `git fetch`, luego recien debes hacer el `git pull` para traer los cambios del repo remoto

Comment: @LF, cuando realizas `git pull` no necesitas hacer `git fetch` ya que **pull** hace eso por ti. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que estas consultando la rama correcta en tu repositorio GitHub, según recuerdo la rama principal por defecto es "main", quiza podrías estar alojando dos ramas, la rama "main" y la rama "master":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien puedes seleccionar que rama será la principal por defecto en la sección de preferecias:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]